# In Illustrator, how do I paste but re-size to fit artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cc-2014, artboard

In Adobe Illustrator CC (latest version) I often find myself copy/pasting artwork from one file to another.

The problem is the artwork in one file is often larger than the destination Artboard, so I have to zoom out, re-size, then move back onto Artboard ... etc.

Is there a way I can 'smart paste' by telling illustrator to paste it, re-size it and fit it somewhere on the target Artboard?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: @Joonas I think the "duplicate" you've posted is the opposite of what Ciwan wants. They want to paste _into_ the size of the existing artboard, not alter it to fit to the pasted image

Comment: @SaturnEye is right.

Comment: @SaturnsEye I think you are mistaking the question to the selected answer. The question, from the title to the description, is clearly about fitting object to the artboard. I suspect he chose Scott's answer because it also worked in his specific situation.

Comment: @Joonas Ah, I see, you're correct.

Comment: When one gets the answer from the linked question, how do I mark my question here as resolved?

Comment: You can't. The way SE handles duplicate questions is not perfect. If enough people agree that this is a duplicate, this question gets closed and that's pretty much it. If an answer in another question answers your question, you can only upvote it.

Comment: Or a mod can just close it after reading the comments

Comment: @Matt Nah... Impossible.